# Visualize JSF facelets inclusion

Tags: jsf

This is a simple question: is there a tool or method that allows me to visualize from what set of Facelet template files my view is constructed?

Background: I find myself constantly searching for popups and reusable chunks I have stashed away in their own little facelets. Now if one is causing issues, I have to go down a hierarchy  of includes to figure out which view is actually including the facelet. Right now this means I'm searching all template files for component id strings, then for each of the files that include that string, I search for the filename of that template, then lookup all templates that `ui:include` that file until I find a file that is not mentioned in an `ui:include` tag.

I imagine that there must be a tool that visualizes this as a tree/forest structure for any given search term. Is there? And if not, how would you go about writing one?